# Is Java disabled in Opera for Windows (NPAPI plugin)?

Tags: java, plugins, opera, npapi

I've installed Opera version 34.0.2036.25 and I am surprised to see that the Java plugin isn't detected, maybe the [Java plugin was disabled as in Chrome](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml) :

http://www.java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp

```
We are unable to verify if Java is currently installed and enabled in your browser.
If you have installed Java and there is an error with the verification, there could be a configuration issue (eg. browser, Java control panel, security settings) or the Java plug-in is blocked by the browser. Try restarting your browser before trying to verify the installation again, and check that the browser allows Java to run.
```

If I use Firefox or Opera 30.0.1835.88 there is no problem. I was seeing the [Opera *changelog*](http://www.opera.com/docs/changelogs/windows/) and didn't find anything related to NPAPI or Java Plugin being disabled. The weird thing is that if I go to the Plug-ins configuration page of Opera (Settings > Websites > Manage individual plug-ins) I see the Java(TM) plugin "enabled":

[image: Opera plugins configuration page]

Comment: I see the same thing.  Same Opera and Java verson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ever Since Opera 15 , the browser was [Chromium](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/11/the-final-countdown-for-npapi.html) based and once Google no longer had support for **NPAPI** plugins in Chrome, neither did Opera.

**NPAPI** was no longer supported in version 32 or 33 of Opera

Comment: The weird thing is that in [Opera's desktop team blog is stated that NPAPI is back in version 34](http://www.opera.com/blogs/desktop/2015/10/opera-developer-34-0-2023-0-update/) ...

Comment: Yes they do state that, however they also mention "For Now" and you are not using the same version that they mentioned in the article (34.0.2036.25 vs. 34.0.2023.0 in the article) so i can only conclude that the support for NPAPI is no longer. @Imiguelmh

Comment: Did you found some official declaration or entry blog where they drop the support for NPAPI?

Comment: @Imiguelmh, I was not able to find any official declaration of a recent dropped support of NPAPI. Even with playing around with Opera myself though, I was still not able to get the Java plug-in to be recognized